# Bivariate Transformation of Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> **Problem.** If $X$ and $Y$ measure the lifetimes of two components operating independently. Suppose each has density (in unit of 100 hours)
>
> $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^2}, & \text{if } x > 1 \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere}, \end{cases} $$
>
> If $Z = \sqrt{XY}$ measures the quality of the system, show that $Z$ has density function
>
> $$ f(z) = \begin{cases} 4\frac{\ln(z)}{z^3}, & \text{if } z > 1 \\ 0, &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

I use the substitutions $Z = \sqrt{XY}$ and $U = Y$ to obtain that the Jacobian is $-2z/u$, but then when I try to solve for the marginal distribution of $z$, I obtain a divergent integral!  My joint distribution function for $u$ and $z$ comes out to be $2 z^{-3} u^{-1}$.  I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When substituting $x=z^2/u$ and $y=u$ into 
$$
f_{Z,U}(z,u)=|J|f_X(x)f_Y(y)=|J|f_X(z^2/u)f_Y(u),
$$
do not forget that both densities are non-zero only when the variable is greater than $1$. So,
$$
f_{Z,U}(z,u)=\frac{2z}{u}\frac{1}{(z^2/u)^2}\mathbb 1_{\{z^2/u > 1\}}\frac{1}{u^2}\mathbb 1_{\{u>1\}},
$$
and the joint pdf is 
$$
f_{Z,U}(z,u)=\begin{cases} 2z^{-3}u^{-1}, & 1<u<z^2,\cr 0, & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I appreciate this, but what exactly was the method used for establishing that $ u < z^2 $?  That's the only part that I was struggling with.

Comment: $x=\frac{z^2}{u} > 1$.